# Connecting Asp.net Core application with external database provider

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, azure, asp.net-core, database-connection

I am hosting Asp.net Core 1.0 application on Azure and SQL server Database on other database provider, i have tried different database host. Hosting Database on azure works perfectly with this connection string:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:biznsdbserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Invento;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={MyUserName};Password={MyPasword};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

But when i try to connect with other like smarterasp.net, gearhost etc using connection strings given below connection fails although the database is there.

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:mssql5.gear.host,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=MyUserName;Password=MyPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

or

```
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=SQL5027.SmarterASP.NET;Initial Catalog=DB_A18B68_Invento;User Id=MyUserName;Password=MyPassword;"
```

is there any problem in connection string or something else?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "problem in connection"? What error?

Comment: @J.Doe Application is not connected to database. Connection to Database is not established whereas database is there.

Comment: @Fahad Specifically, what is the error message? Have you configured your database server to accept network connections from your application?

Comment: @mason The Error is SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

Comment: That's pretty important information, you should have included that in your question from the beginning. I would check my database server to make sure it's using a valid certificate.

Comment: How can i check for valid certificate, in gearhost or smarterasp no option like it is available .Is there any issuse In my connection string changing TrustServerCertificate=False .

Comment: That is an issue, because now you can't trust that whoever you make a connection to is who they say they are. Which is why having a certificate you can trust is important.

Comment: I have 1 year ban in chatrooms...

Comment: I've had alot of trouble with SmarterASP.net when it comes to timeouts on database connections. It may actually be a problem specific with them. This is what they tell you to do: https://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a1540/the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-obtaining-a-connection-from-the-pool_.aspx But none of these solutions worked for me. I get intermittent database timeouts several times per hour. In fact this occurs within my application and when trying to connect with SQL Manager. I really think they have issues, but if you find the magic connection string, please let us all know.